# Parse textfile without fixed structure using python dictionary and Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, text-files

I have .txt file without specific separators and to parse it, I need to count character by character to know where starts and ends a column. To do so, I constructed a Python dictionary where the keys are the column names and the values are the number of characters that takes each column:

```
headers = {first_col: 3, second_col: 5, third_col: 2, ... nth_col: n_chars}
```

Having that in mind, I know that the three first columns of the following line in the .txt file

```
ABC123-3YN0000000001203ABC123*TESTINGLINE
```

first_col: ABC
second_col: 123-3
third_col: YN

I want to know if there is any pandas function that helps me to parse this .txt taking into account this particular condition and (if possible) using my `headers` dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary is dangerous because the order is not guaranteed.  Meaning, if you picked `third_col` first, you've thrown of your entire scheme.  You can fix this by using lists.  From there, you can use `pd.read_fwf` to read a fixed with formatted text file.

**Solution**

```
names = ['first_col', 'second_col', 'third_col']
widths = [3, 5, 2]

pd.read_fwf(
    'myfile.txt',
    widths=widths,
    names=names
)

  first_col second_col third_col
0       ABC      123-3        YN
```

You can also use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` library and make sure you keep the order you want by passing an iterator that produces tuples in the correct order

```
from collections import OrderedDict

names = ['first_col', 'second_col', 'third_col']
widths = [3, 5, 2]

header = OrderedDict(zip(names, widths))

pd.read_fwf(
    'myfile.txt',
    widths=header.values(),
    names=header.keys()
)

  first_col second_col third_col
0       ABC      123-3        YN
```

**Demonstration**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

txt = """ABC123-3YN0000000001203ABC123*TESTINGLINE"""

names = ['first_col', 'second_col', 'third_col']
widths = [3, 5, 2]

header = OrderedDict(zip(names, widths))

pd.read_fwf(
    'myfile.txt',
    widths=header.values(),
    names=header.keys()
)

  first_col second_col third_col
0       ABC      123-3        YN
```

Comment: io.common.StringIO is better than https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO?

Comment: Also note that: "The OrderedDict constructor and update() method both accept keyword arguments, but their order is lost because Python’s function call semantics pass-in keyword arguments using a regular unordered dictionary."

Comment: In regards to `StringIO`  I'm not making any claims as to which is better.  I used `pd.io.common` because I know you have it imported already.

Comment: In regards to `OrderedDict`, I've fixed the issue